# How to set an image as background of an annotation in MuPDF?

Tags: c, mupdf

I want to set an image as background of an annotation in MuPDF using following code:

```
fz_context *ctx = doc->ctx;
const fz_matrix *page_ctm = &annot->page->ctm;
image_document *image_doc = (image_document *)fz_open_document(ctx, "/Users/zidane/Downloads/a.jpg");

fz_image *image = image_doc->image;
fz_matrix local_ctm = *page_ctm;

float w = image->w * DPI / image->xres;
float h = image->h * DPI / image->yres;

fz_pre_scale(&local_ctm, w, h);
fz_pre_translate(&local_ctm, 0, -1);
fz_fill_image(dev, image, &local_ctm, 1);
```

Can someone tell me why it does not work?

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Image is not displayed

Comment: And you compiled with all the warnings on and doesn't give you **any** warning at all?

Comment: Yes, I could compile the code without any warning. I followed the guide on this: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324019/i-have-inserted-an-image-into-pdf-digital-signature-layer-n2-using-mupdf-but-it/26821977#26821977?newreg=df89c32c2f7f41eeb38485a2ff77ef78

Comment: @UniCell: Sorry, I corrected the code that I used.